# How to find Top Losers for 1 day , 1 Month based on Historical data

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure for storing the historical data .

```
  CREATE TABLE `historical_data` (
      `symbol_name` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
      `current_day` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `open_val` varchar(50) ,
      `low_val` varchar(50) ,
     `close_val` varchar(50) ,
     `high_val` varchar(50) ,
      `prevclose_val` varchar(50) 
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

And this is my sample data

From the current date i am trying to find out Top Losers for 1 week and 1 month from the current date

I have tried as following

```
select symbol_name, (prevclose_val-close_val) as losers  from historical_data 
order by losers asc limit 10
```

Could you please tell me how can i make this work for 1 week and 1 month .

The sample data wil be in this format

```
 Insert Into historical_data values('SBIN','14-DEC-2015','300.10','289.00','305.10','309.90','256.30');
```

sql fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47794

Comment: Why do you add the date as a varchar? Use `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIME` instead, then you can use the date specific arithmetical functions built-into mysql.

Comment: The sample data seems to be missing.  Also, it would help to mention what specific errors you are getting on what you have already tried.

Comment: @PaulJAbernathy i have added sample data .

Comment: What do you mean 'for 1 week/1 month'? between? for each day? for each week/month?

Comment: Before you can work with that date, better convert it to a proper date format. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: Please show sample input (table data) and sample output (expected query result for that data)

Comment: The sample output is , please see the top loosers section  in this link http://www.finalaya.com/

Comment: Sample output doesn't help if we don't have the input used to produce that...

Comment: added sample input http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47794

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this*:

```
select * from (select symbol_name , (prevclose_val-close_val) as losers,'daily' as `type` from historical_data where current_day >= '2015-12-14' order by losers asc limit 10 ) as sub_daily
union
select * from (select symbol_name , (prevclose_val-close_val) as losers,'weekly' as `type` from historical_data where current_day >= '2015-12-7' order by losers asc limit 10 ) as sub_weekly
union
select * from (select symbol_name , (prevclose_val-close_val) as losers,'monthly' as `type` from historical_data where current_day >= '2015-11-14' order by losers asc limit 10 ) as sub_monthly;
```

By the way, you should really change your date field from "varchar" into "DATE" or "DATETIME" and use `yyyy-mm-dd` format for your dates. That way you can use MySQL to do calculations on your date.

* this query requires your `current_day` field to be a `date` or `datetime` type.